# Binding to ApplicationData RoamingSettings Values crashes app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Im trying to bind directly to the Values property of ApplicationData RoamingSettings container but the app crashes. The value I type in the textbox get saved and loaded but the App does crash instantly after the value changes thru the binding. My question is should you bind to Values directly or use LoadState/SaveState?

After some fiddeling I get the following error:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
HResult=-2147467261
Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IMap`2.Insert(K key, V value)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Insert[K,V](IMap`2 _this, K key, V value)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.MapToDictionaryAdapter.Indexer_Set[K,V](K key, V value)
   at App10.MainPage.<ChangeValue>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c__DisplayClass2`1.<OutputAsyncCausalityEvents>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.<>c__DisplayClass1.<OutputWaitEtwEvents>b__0()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.ContinuationWrapper.Invoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetActionLogDelegate>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<.cctor>b__6(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeInContext(Object thisObj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.Invoke()
InnerException:
```

The app exits with

```
The program '[7124] App10.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I would make it really easy to bind to settings in XAML. Does the RoamingSettings implement IObservableMap correctly or is there some disposing happening? My code is based on the BlankPage template.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace App10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public IPropertySet Settings { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            Settings = ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.CreateContainer("MySettings", ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always).Values;
            if (!Settings.ContainsKey("Hello"))
            {
                Settings.Add("Hello", "StartingValue");
            }
            this.InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

And my XAML-file.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App10.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App10"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Settings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Hello,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="310,249,620,491"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register for the DataChanged event and add a event handler that will update your Roaming Settings "Hello" with the new value of the TextBox. This will ensure that your app can handle modifications to your roaming settings correctly.

See this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.datachanged.aspx) link for an example.

Comment: Well I can do that also when the app does not crash. Are you saying that when DataChanged is fired it destroys something inside the ApplicationData object? But if I use LocalSettings i get the same error.

Comment: No, I am not saying that DataChanged destroys the ApplicationData object. 

Once you change Roaming settings from your XAML, you need to re-save and commit the settings - for example, Settings.Values["Hello"] = newValue. Are you doing that?  In order to properly use roaming app data it is imperative that you listen to the DataChanged event and take the appropriate action to update settings correctly.

Here is a sample that might be useful for you to understand roaming settings - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ApplicationData-sample-fb043eb2

Hope that helps!

Comment: You can see the excact code im using. in my question. Im not showing a snippit im showing the exact code. I have no problem getting saving values. It is the binding directly to Values. I can create a wrapper with ObservervableDictionary and auto save data but im trying to understand why I cant bind directly to the IPropertySet that is provided from ApplicationDataContainer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to a windows 8 machine right now to verify. Are you saying that your code crashes, if you use IPropertySet and also register for the DataChanged event? Does it crash when load the settings or change the settings or both?

Comment: @JishaPuniyani & Fredrik. What is the resolution to this problem? I see the same crash when binding directly to the IPropertySet.